# How to convert geojason file to topojson without loss of information or distortion?

Tags: d3.js, geojson, shapefile, topojson

I want to map the major fishing areas and the divisions in an interactive map using d3.js. I got the shapefiles from http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home?uuid=ac02a460-da52-11dc-9d70-0017f293bd28.  I am following the instructions given in “Let’s make a map” https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/. I also want to keep all the information so I wrote this in the terminal:

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON subunitsall.json FAO_AREAS.shp;

topojson -o FAOallsubunits.json -p -- subunitsall.json

The conversion seems to go ok in geojson, but there is something wrong with the topojson final result. Some areas are not correct. I checked with mapshaper.org and some polygons are definitely wrong. [Look at one of the areas over Alaska](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvjbS.png)

Comment: This may be a anti-meridian clipping issue. Can you share the output topojson?

Comment: Here is a link to the file: http://www.databayou.com/stackoverflow/FAOallsubunits.json Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data looks more or less ok once projected: [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/830a5bfbd33db8f7589d55e68b6b471f), though I see one missing segment (top of Greenland) I'm on the road so I can't check very definitively, but it may be that mapshaper was not producing the desired output as it may be expecting Cartesian coordinates. In a Cartesian/2d representation, any wedge that touches the North Pole is four sided. In spherical coordinates its just a three sided wedge (any point 90 degrees north is the same regardless of east/west). This may be why some northern areas appear wrong.

Comment: I also have an orthographic projection with D3.js and it does not have most of the subareas in the Pacific: [link] (http://www.databayou.com/stackoverflow/area1/globe.html)

Comment: I'll take a look late tomorrow - I'm currently on the road and in the air tomorrow, but have not forgotten about this.